# How to get the selecteditem from a listpicker as string in c# for windows phone application

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml

this is my xaml code

```
<toolkit:ListPicker SelectionChanged="CountryLP_SelectionChanged" Header="--Select Mode--"  ItemsSource="{Binding CountryListdata,  ElementName=this}" x:Name="CountryLP" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding country}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding country}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

during pageload, the control automatically goes to the event CountryLP_SelectionChanged
 I want to get the selected item string

This is a c# code to set Values to the `listpicker`

```
//to get values from webservice
public class CountryList
{
    public String id{ get; set; }
    public String country{ get; set; }
}

private void CountryLP_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CountryLP.SelectedItem == null)
        return;

    //var s= (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem;
    CountryList s= CountryLP.SelectedItem as CountryList;
    //string s= CountryLP.SelectedItem as string;
    //string s= CountryLP.SelectedItem.toString();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```

I have tried several method, but not getting the string value. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: xaml code

<toolkit:ListPicker SelectionChanged="CountryLP_SelectionChange ItemsSource="{Binding CountryListdata}" x:Name="CountryLP" >
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding country}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>

Comment: Any error or exception?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. You can handle this exception by adding this to configuration file.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Also try

```
var content = ((ListPickerItem)CountryLP.SelectedItem).Content;
```

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); which displays a value
MyProject.CountryList

Comment: What value it displays? and what you want?

Comment: i want the item that i selected from dropdown.the string value. but whichever value i select what i get is MyProject.CountryList.